# Name for secret unofficial/personal skunkworks project

Tags: skunkworks

> A [skunkworks project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunkworks_project) is a project developed by a small and loosely structured group of people who research and develop a project primarily for the sake of radical innovation.
>
> It is an especially enriched environment that is intended to help a small group of individuals design a new idea by escaping routine organizational procedures. The research and development (R&D) workers in a skunkworks are usually specially selected, given special resources, and work on a crash basis to create an innovation.

What if there is no managerial approval, and one individual embarks on a (legal) project during their own time, in secret (since there is no formal approval) with the intent of bringing about radical innovation?

**Is there a name for such a project?**

<sub>Some successful examples would be interesting.</sub>

Comment: Volunteering? Since you are presumably doing your real job at the same time. (Or a problem if it is secret because it isn't allowed)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_operation would come to mind for an idea.

Comment: -1 This is a very loosely defined list question.

Comment: @Lego: How about you ignore the list part if you hate lists, and instead let people answer the main question, Is there a name for such a project?

Comment: Well the name given to a skunkworks-like project, as you have stated is a "skunkworks project".

Comment: A personal skunkworks project?

Comment: @keshlam As explained in the link in the question, "Skunkworks comes from a lil abner comic and **refers specifically to company sanctioned "thinktanks".**

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the source. However, I disagree on the usage. I know the guy who wrote IBM's first prototype XSLT processor -- as a personal project, during a few days when he was out of the office due to being sick. Since his goal was to show the company that this was a useful tool, I believe he would call it a skunkworks project despite it being "sanctioned" only after the fact. I'd call it a highly successful one, since that code evolved into LotusXSL and thence into Apache Xalan. You may be right about the defined usage, but the usage by folks who do it has diverged.

Comment: Maybe this fits in english and language usage? http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If it doesn't have resources in the form of actual people, a budget, and some specific goal, then it is not even "a project", let alone a skunkworks project. There is nothing wrong with calling it a "personal project" (and obviously great things can come of that) but anything beyond that would assume that it has been sanctioned by the employer and is pretentious.

Answer (score 5):

A skunkworks project implies a team taken out of formal structures, but still with some form of oversight within an organisation.

If you are doing things on your own time, that would be called a "personal project".

Comment: Makes sense. "Personal project" though suggests something unrelated to the main business, and not sanctioned either  as was Google's now defunct [20% time](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/16/google-20-percent-time_n_3768586.html).

Comment: Are you officially getting time off for this project, or are you doing it in your own time?

Comment: Own time, as mentioned.

Comment: Well, then it is just a "personal project". It might be beneficial to the company, it might not. They have no vested interest if it fails, maybe not even if it works.

Comment: Look at it like this, if I do unpaid work on my own time that might help the Army, I don't get to call it a "military project" or call myself a "defence contractor". If the people you are doing it for aren't sanctioning it, then using a term that suggests they do is dishonest and has potential legal implications.